# Unable to use bazel outside of drive C

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

This might be very silly question but please forgive me. I am trying to figure out why I can't get bazel to work outside the `C` drive. I am new to windows, is there anything similar to mac where we set variables that can be used outside the 
directory they reside in?

I have bazel.exe at the root of drive `C` and I can access it fine within that directory or in other directories with absolute path to bazel like `C:\bazel`. But I want to access it from drive `D` just with `bazel`.

I have added `C:\bazel` to user `Path` variable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To have access to an .exe in the root of c: drive you'd have to add `C:\` to the path, what isn't a good idea for security reasons. Better put that file into a subfolder of `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` and add that to the path.

Comment: Moved bazel to `C:\Users\Me\bazel` so now I can access it via `%USERPROFILE%\bazel`, but still no luck with path configuration

Comment: Is `C:\Users\Me\bazel` a folder containing `bazel.exe`? And is `%USERPROFILE` resp. `%USERPROFILE%\bazel` in the path?